# An integral equation in $L^2[0,1]$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the integral equation
\begin{equation*}
f(t)=g(t)+\int_0^t (t-s)f(s)ds,\quad 0\leq t\leq 1,
\end{equation*}
where $g\colon [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a given Riemann integrable function and the unknown function is 
$f\colon [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. What can you say about this equation in terms of existence and uniqueness 
in $L^2[0,1]$?

Unfortunately, I have no idea about the question. I know it is wrong to ask questions that I did not do anything about but I could not anyway. I don't know the meaning of the integral of $(t-s)f(s)$, and we are adding some given function and we have the old function $f$. I have no idea about the equation. Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's one tip: Let $Tf$ denote the right hand side. Then any solution is a fixed point in that it solves $Tf=f$. Can you prove this is a contraction mapping wrt $L^2([0,1])$?

Comment: Thanks, I will think about it.